# nth-child with skipping arbitrary number of levels

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="item">First</div>
    <div class="item">Second</div>
    <div class="item">Third</div>
</div>
<div class="list">
    <div><div class="item">First</div></div>
    <div><div class="item">Second</div></div>
    <div><div class="item">Third</div></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.list .item { background: #00ff00; }
.list .item:nth-child(1n+2) { background: none; } /*remove bg on all but the 1st one*/
```

How do I get the 2nd list of items to behave like the first?

I know that I can do:

```
.list div:nth-child(1n+2) .item { background: none; }
```

but the point is that there may be an arbitrary number of `div` levels between the `list` and the `item`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dgnvjsf/)

Comment: Does the nested `.item` fit its container div in its entirety?

Comment: Also, you can just use `:first-child` instead of having to deal with an `:nth-child(n+2)` override, unless you're relying on an override for some other purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If `:nth-child()` will only apply to the first level of descendants, but `.item` may also appear in the first level, [you will probably need two separate selectors](https://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/2dgnvjsf/1):

```
.list > .item:nth-child(n+2), 
.list > div:nth-child(n+2) .item { background: none; }
```

Notice the `>` between the first two selectors, and the space between the last two, in the second line. The `>` ensures that `:nth-child()` only applies to the first level of descendants after the `.list` element. The space ensures that the innermost `.item` elements will always be targeted regardless of their depth.

Also note that `1n+2` is equivalent to `n+2`; the 1 is implied [just like a mathematical coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient).

Comment: Yea I guess that works :/ I'd like have a definition that doesn't have the `div` in it though. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Halcyon: If you mean something like `.list > :nth-child(n+2) .item`, then that's the best you can do I'm afraid.

Comment: Can't you just remove the div, yea like in the comment, saw it after posting

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
.list div:nth-child(1n+2) .item { background: none; }
```

to this

```
.list > .item:nth-child(n+2), .list > div:nth-child(n+2) .item { 
    background: none;
}
```